# Why is T-SQL EXEC not returning decimals?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query that I've turned into a stored proc:

```
create procedure GetAmount as
declare @amnt decimal(25,2)

select @amnt=66666.67 
set @amnt = @amnt/3.00

print @amnt
return @amnt
```

If I print @amnt, it returns 22222.22

But if I use EXEC and assign it to a variable:

```
declare @x numeric(25,2)
exec @x=SP_GetAmount()
print @x
```

it returns 22222.00

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` [returns an integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). Use an output parameter.

```
create procedure GetAmount 
    @amnt decimal(25,2) OUTPUT
as

select @amnt=66666.67 
set @amnt = @amnt/3.00

GO
```

And to call it:

```
declare @x numeric(25,2)
exec SP_GetAmount() @amnt = @x OUTPUT
print @x
```

Comment: Thanks Ed - I figured it was something simple.